# numeralsToTxt() method in Axapta

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012

When i am trying to print `info(numeralsToTxt(3492.4069));`    It give me the out put as `*** Three Thousand Four Hundred Ninety Two and 41/100`. Now I want it to be `*** Three Thousand Four Hundred Ninety Two and 406/1000`  when i check the method numeralsToTxt() I find the function `frac()` returns .41

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frac()` is not returning .41. It is `decRound(frac(_num), 2)` which is returning .41. The second argument to the decRound method is the number of decimal places you want.

What you could do is change

`int     numOfPennies = (decRound(frac(_num), 2) * 100) mod 100;`

to

`int     numOfPennies = (decRound(frac(_num), 3) * 1000) mod 1000;`

Then, change the output string at the bottom of the `numeralsToTxt` method to display `'/1000'` instead of `'/100'`

The actual output will be 407/1000, not 406/1000 because it will round up.

Comment: thanks lot... just another quick question I have a value as 234.26 but i want to display it like 234.260... any in built function you aware of?